# Does my Skype status ever change to 'Away' automatically?

Tags: skype, instant-messaging, status

Does my Skype status ever automatically change to `Away`? If so, when does this happen?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it can, after you specify a number of minutes.

See image below:  Go to the Skype Options, then to the General Settings, and then you can specify when you want Skype to change your status to away.
[image]
Hope that helps!

Comment: Is that haven't used Skype for 5 minutes or haven't used computer?

Comment: @Casebash: haven't used computer for 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to comment, still, so - have to bump it.. Just felt that the answer was incomplete! :)

At their FAQ page, [What is a status setting and how do I change it in Skype for Windows desktop?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA3501/what-is-a-status-setting-and-how-do-i-change-it-in-skype-for-windows-desktop), it's also mentioned how to get Skype to NEVER report idle time (?) /set status:

> If you have a value of **0**, you will never appear as **Away** unless you manually set this status by clicking on your status icon and selecting it from the list.

P.S.
Got here via Google query, "[skype block idle time](https://www.google.com/search?q=skype+block+idle+time)".